# Imagen del marcador demasiado grande Google Maps

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Estoy personalizando un marcador del mapa pero al momento de cargar el mapa me la muestra en un tamaño muy exagerado y no en el tamaño del marcador, intente probar colocando un vector, pero me mostraba el siguiente error.

```
 com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.common.apiexception.b: Failed to decode image. The provided image must be a Bitmap.
```

Quiero que el marcador me quede la siguiente manera y en el tamaño por defecto.

[image: Imagen marcador ejemplo]

Comment: Bienvenido Carlos es importante agregar el código que estas tratando, aporta más información, me parece que estas tratando de cargar un vector asset. Revisa [ask] y realiza el [tour] del sitio,saludos.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Para resolver el detalle de la excepción que te está mandando, al momento de usar la imagen en el método de new MarkerOptions() icon, sería:

```
.icon(bitmapDescriptorFromVector(this, R.drawable.marker));

private BitmapDescriptor bitmapDescriptorFromVector(Context context, @DrawableRes  int vectorDrawableResourceId) {
     Drawable background = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.ic_map_pin_filled_blue_48dp);
     background.setBounds(0, 0, background.getIntrinsicWidth(), background.getIntrinsicHeight());
     Drawable vectorDrawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, vectorDrawableResourceId);
     vectorDrawable.setBounds(40, 20,vectorDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth() + 40, vectorDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight() + 20);
     Bitmap bitmap = 
     Bitmap.createBitmap(background.getIntrinsicWidth(), background.getIntrinsicHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
     Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
     background.draw(canvas);
     vectorDrawable.draw(canvas);
     return BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bitmap);
}
```

Te adjunto la liga de referencia donde responden tu duda 
[Liga Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42365658/custom-marker-in-google-maps-in-android-with-vector-asset-icon)

Comment: Vale muchas gracias por la información, me funcionan los vectores pero me aparecen los marcadores de un tamaño casi lo mismo que la pantalla del móvil, prácticamente igual como la que subí arriba y no me quedan en el tamaño original, es una imagen png de 512 x 512.

Comment: Ya lo pude solucionar, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes realizarlo de una manera alternativa, determinando primero un int para la altura, y otro int para el ancho que desees.

```
int height = 60; //Personalizalo como quieras
int width = 60;
```

Posteriormente, llamas al método BitmapDrawable para cargar la imágen, luego con el objeto Bitmap, le aplicas el tamaño:

```
BitmapDrawable bitmapdraw = (BitmapDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.TU_IMAGEN_AQUI);
                             Bitmap b = bitmapdraw.getBitmap();
                             Bitmap smallMarker = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(b, width, height, false);
```

Y por último, usas el objeto MarkerOptions para ubicar tu marcador, con tu imagen personalizada

```
MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
                              markerOptions.position(new LatLng(latitud, longitud));
                              markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(smallMarker));
                              mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
```